# Vim discards input characters at startup

Tags: vim

I have been driven crazy for years with Vim's behavior of throwing away input characters. I start vim like this:

```
$ vim file.c
```

and then immediately begin typing commands. However, Vim discards some of those characters, causing the wrong action to take place.

Is there something we can put in the `.vimrc` to solve this issue?

Vim should be able to change the TTY to raw mode without flushing buffered input.

---

Update: the issue is more precisely characterized, thanks to the following investigation method. I created a script called `delayvim` which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 2.0
vim "$@"
```

Now during this two second pause I can type something like `iabc<ESC>` and then when Vim comes up, everything is cool: the command is processed, `abc` is inserted and Vim pops back into command mode, with the cursor backed up over the `c`.  **Thus, it is not simply flushing the TTY input buffer**.

**However,** if I keep typing during this delay, for instance `iabcdefghijk...`, it **will** sometimes lose a letter or two of the alphabet that is typed right around the time when the `sleep` terminates and the editor launches. For instance, here is the result of one trial I just performed:

```
abcdefghilmn_
~
~
```

Where are `jk`, oops? I am sure I typed them. I didn't type very fast; my cadence was around 4-5 strokes per second, yet two consecutive events disappeared.

Basically, it might be trying to interrogate the terminal, and in the process discarding the input that is mixed up in the response. Or it could be a combination of reading some of the prior input, then flushing the input buffer and losing the rest.

Comment: Not that this is off-topic here, but there's a [Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). They may be better at answering this.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Ah, I completely forgot about that site.

Comment: Much better than SO or that Vim SE for that kind of question: the vim_use mailing list or the issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl Wrote about this to the list several years ago; there was one reply that wasn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

2 points that might help:

1) are you being sure to hit `i` first, to enter input mode, so that all characters you type afterward should go ahead and be seen in your buffer (on the screen?).  Otherwise the letters you type will be processed as commands, which will often do nothing, especially if you're starting an empty file.

Note that `a` and `o` are other common commands for telling vim that you are about to begin inserting text starting with the next keystroke.

2) In case the reason on your system has to do with speed, you can look for options to change what happens at startup.  For example, if you put this in your .vimrc file

> autocmd VimEnter * :sleep 5

Then after processing other startup files, vim or gvim will literally do nothing for 5 seconds before showing your file on the screen.  On my system, I was able to type `iabcdef` during those 5 seconds and when the time was up, I did see `abcdef` entered into my text file.

If your file was not empty, beware, as (depending on your settings) your vim installation might be kindly returning you to the last place you were editing inside the file, and you will have inserted the text there, instead of at the start.

If this doesn't work, you could try to find other things vim can do (on the web, or using :help from within vim) and program it using autocmd to happen at startup to see if it helps.

Comment: I am typing  a full command from command mode. But, am I imagining this problem? I went one level above and made a `delayvim` shell script which calls `sleep 0.3` and then invokes `vim`. If I just type `i` during that sleep, Vim ends up in insert mode; I cannot reproduce it dropping `i`.

Comment: Aha, Starman. With `delayvim`, I can see character drop. It's not flushing the TTY buffer, though; it drops something in the middle. I will update the question.